# Fortran: (mis)matching dynamic types

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I am copying a variable of certain class in another of the same class. The compiler happily compiles this but I am worried that at run time the dynamic types may differ. Do I need to test that the two objects are of the same dynamic type to prevent copying rectangle in a square say or may I trust the compiler? What happens if a rectangle is copied in a square accidentally?

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
type :: simVars
        class(stateVars), dimension(:), allocatable :: svars
        integer                                     :: count_
    contains
        procedure :: init    => init_simVars
        procedure :: destroy => dest_simVars
        procedure :: add     => add_to_simVars              ! adds an observation to the time series
end type simVars

subroutine init_simVars(this,n)
!--> VERSION 1
    class(simVars), intent(inout) :: this
    integer,        intent(in)    :: n

    allocate( this%svars(n) )

    this%count_ = 0
end subroutine init_simVars

subroutine init_simVars(this,n,sVarsIni)
!--> VERSION 2
    class(simVars), intent(inout) :: this
    integer,        intent(in)    :: n
    class(stateVars), intent(in)  :: sVarsIni

    allocate( this%svars(n),source=sVarsIni )

    this%count_ = 0
end subroutine init_simVars

subroutine add_to_simvars(this,svars)
    class(simVars),   intent(inout) :: this
    class(stateVars), intent(in)    :: svars

    this%count_ = this%count_+1

    this%svars(this%count_) = svars
end subroutine add_to_simvars

subroutine doSimulation(simHist,sVarsIni)
    class(simVars),   intent(out) :: simHist
    class(stateVars), intent(in)  :: sVarsIni
         !--> dynamic type 'stateVars1'

    class(stateVars), allocatable :: sVars   ! will be source allocated from 'iniState'

    ! initialize the state of the economy
    allocate( sVars, source=sVarsIni )    ! "copies" 'sVarsIni' in 'sVars'

    ! initialize 'simHist'
    !--> VERSION 1:
    call simHist%init(nYears)
    !--> VERSION 2:
    call simHist%init(nYears,iniState)

    ! save today's variables
    call simHist%add(sVars)
    ...
end subroutine doSimulation
```

Compiler (ifort 14) happily compiles both versions but I strongly suspect that VERSION 1 is wrong. In `init_simVars` `this%svars` will be allocated to dynamic type `stateVars`, in `add_to_simvars` `sVars` will have dynamic type `stateVars1` and a copy in `this%sVars` (of type `stateVars`) will be attempted. I am quite surprised that the compiler compiles this even though it cannot determine the dynamic type of `sVars` in `add_to_simvars`. What would happen at run time, a seg fault or what?

VERSION 2 I believe is correct however I am somewhat reluctant to trust the compiler here therefore I am thinking I should `ASSERT` that `this%sVars` and `sVars` have the same dynamic type (`ASSERT(SAME_TYPE_AS(this%sVars, sVars) )`)? Is this a real concern or am I worried too much?

Another question is what happens when I do `allocate( this%svars(n),source=sVarsIni )`. I want to allocate the array `this%sVars` to be of size `n` and dynamic type `sVarsIni`. However `sVarsIni` is a scalar. Will it do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in these lines

```
allocate( this%svars(n) )
```

vs.

```
allocate( this%svars(n),source=sVarsIni )
```

where `this%svars` is `class(svars)` allocatable array and svarsIni is an `class(stateVars)` dummy argument.

That indeed changes a lot.

In the first case, it allocates it to the declared type, which is `svars`, in the other case it allocates to the dynamic type of the dummy argument, which is at least `stateVars`.

If you do version 1, it should than fail at `add_to_simvars`, because the dynamic types won't match.

I don't know if you overloaded the assignment in there or not. If you didn't it shouldn't even compile, because of the intrinsic assignment of polymorphic objects.

Comment: You are totally right, I kind of thought what you are saying but I overlooked that I have overloaded `=` on the parent class `stateVars`. That means the compiler always knows what to do with `this%svars(this%count_) = svars`. To summarize VERSION1 wouldn't have compiled if I had not messed up with the assignment operator. But then VERSION2 won't compile either without overloading `=`, will it? Because the compiler cannot determine that the dynamic types are the same. ... Tried it and it really does not compile without overloading `=`.

Comment: Yes, the problem for the compiler will be in the  `add_to_simvars`, so it will fail compile in both cases without the overloaded assignment. Version 1 will make problems at runtime.

Comment: One last comment, I have overloaded `=` on the extended class as well. The code compiles, which I think is because if the dynamic types happen to be different the compiler will always be able to call the `=` overloading routine for the parent class. This is legal but will cause a nasty run time error contaminating `this%sVars` therefore using an assertion such as above is definitely useful.

Comment: It very depends on what actually is in the derived types, and what you can or cannot allow from the program logic point of view. I can imagine many situations where the overloaded `=` is just enough to make everything run nicely. In other situations you really need the dynamic types to be the same. You can achieve similar check with `select type`, but in this case, if you place the check in `add_to_simvars` the `same_type_as()` is probably better.